# How to fix: Buttons "loose" OnClickListener when changing the layout in Kotlin

Tags: android, button, kotlin, onclicklistener, setcontentview

I got two layouts in Kotlin, each with one Button and I just want to switch between both. So I added an OnClickListener to both

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button_foward.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            setContentView(R.layout.second)
            button_back.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            })
        })
```

Well, it is actually working. I can go to the second layout and switch back to the first, but i cannot open the second layout again!

I thought I would have to redefine the Listener after changing back to the main view, so I created two separate functions to set the views.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this@MainActivity.createMainScreen()
        })
    }

    fun createMainScreen(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button_foward.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            this@MainActivity.createSecondScreen()
        })
    }
    fun createSecondScreen(){
        setContentView(R.layout.second)
        button_back.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            this@MainActivity.createMainScreen()
        })
    }
```

This way was working, when I tried to get rid of the same problem in Java, but in Kotlin i still can use every Button only once.

How do I solve this? Can (do I have to) reset the Buttons before redefining them?

Or might there be an alternative for the use of setContentView?

Thx for your help!

Comment: From the included code, it is hard to be confident that button_back is set up correctly. Where/when is it assigned? Try setting a breakpoint on the line where it is used to see if it is what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that button_back is not set up correctly.

A cleaner approach might be to have a single layout containing both alternatives, and then setting the visibility of the alternatives in the click handlers.

I really like Anko instead of XML for specifying layouts because it makes these kind of behaviors more readable and self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I thought, directly assigning to the id of the button like

```
button_foward.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {       
                this@MainActivity.createSecondScreen() })
```

should result in the same  like

```
this.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_foward).setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            this@MainActivity.createSecondScreen()})
```

I saw the first code example somewhere in some tutorial and thought this would be the common Kotlin way to do that. Even Android Studio suggested me to do this, but only the second way seems to do what I want in this case.

Well, problem solved :D
Thanks!